# Using logic to assign operators

Tags: logic, operators

so I have this problem and we have to use logic to assign operators to each. Either >, >=, <, <=, != or ==. However, I keep getting one wrong.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruoxu.png)

My answers were:

1. (>)
2. (>)
3. !=
4. <=
5. ==
6. (>)

I suspect I am getting #6 wrong and my guess is either it is >= or <=. However, I can see a reasoning behind both :(

Comment: I didnt find any issue why it is not ==. Can you provide the link of this quiz?

Comment: Not the equals the one after that. The last one is the one I think I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If thats the case, then your one is wrong answer.

Reason:

Lets see that you went out to watch a movie with your best friend. The cost of a ticket is $20. However, you have $50 in your pocket. So you will be able to buy the ticket. So you frient says you have **enough money**. Even though you have $20 in your pocket, wouldn't it be **enough** to buy the ticket? (Of course, yes)

Same way, this question suggests that there is a fixed approval age but the applicant's age is equal or greater than that. So, there are changes of his approval. (If you check the example given in question, you will be able to understand)

Take it as a minimum approval age